# UIWindow becomes NULL when app goes to background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITabBarController` embedded in `UINavigationController` when app loads it show initial `UIViewController` and the `self.view.window` property is  not `NULL`.

But when I put app in background mode and the tap on app icon so app becomes active the `self.view.window` property is `NULL`.

I have property declare in AppDelegate.h `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;`

Then I set it in AppDelegate.m like that `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];` in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

Then i have `[self.window setRootViewController:launchViewController];` and `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];` methods.

Any ideas why this hapens?

Comment: is it a weak property?

Comment: make sure you have these lines of code in didFinishLaunchingMethod,
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = YourViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I have all those methods. I don't have `initialViewController` set in interface builder, because I do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

`self.view.window` can be accessed only when self.view is in foreground.

as the property

`@property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow     *window;`

belong to Hierarchy interface `@interface UIView(UIViewHierarchy)`

Comment: I have property like that `@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;` Then I set it like that `self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];` And I register for `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` so I think that the view is in foreground.

Comment: name it like self.window1 for example

Comment: It doesn't work. The problem is that if I go to another view in `UITabBarController` and come back again to initial view the property is again fine.

Comment: And now I noticed that this happens only when I run the app first time. When I run app again from Xcode everything is OK.

Comment: Can I have the use case where you need to access the `self.view.window`

Comment: In my initial view I have `UICollectionView` and I noticed that when the `self.view.window` is NULL the method `[self.collectionView reloadData]` doesn't work. It get's the data but then doesn't refresh the `UICollectionView`. Method `- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` is not called.

Comment: I also tried this `[self performSelector:@selector(reloadView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];` when I receive notification, but that doesn't work as well.

Comment: Check if cv.dataSource  pointing to your corresponding object when you call reloadData

Comment: I added cv.dataSource and cv.delegate. Now all methods all called but the cv still doesn't want to refresh.

Comment: YOu have added but it's as expected during refresh ?

Comment: I solved the problem by replacing the initial view with itself. Now the view is loaded and everything works. @iDev thank you for your help.